# Migrated web, changed labels, now have problems with residual code - Google map pin hover pops up old web site name

Tags: html, google-maps, migration

I migrated my old web site to new hosting company, wanted to save money by using the same CMS, just changed labels and UI parts that use old site name.

Now there is only one more problem left, I don't have any idea how to remove old name showing on mouse hover on Google Maps pin. Can it be forced to show nothing at all? I just want to get rid of anything that even resembles

Searched through Google maps.js and I'm not sure what to delete or change to.

```
// Create a marker for each place.

markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({

    map: map,

    icon: icon,

    title: place.name, //tried deleting this, nothing changes

    position: place.geometry.location
}));
```

I'm being very cautious about changing the code in Google maps js, don't want to break the site.

Comment: https://imgur.com/xrlcLoE   - this is how it looks like

Comment: You already tried deleting `title: place.name` but the title remains? Are you setting a title to your marker somewhere else in your code?